# Import Namespace syntax to import "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to Import the NameSpace of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` into my aspx C# code.  I have no code behind.  The normal import NameSpace method isn't working.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" %>
```

I need to open Outlook and dynamically generate the email body with HTML formatting.
I get the following error when running the code:

```
The type or namespace name 'Outlook' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll` included in your project?

Comment: I don't understand why I was down voted.  That is my issue.  I do not have access to Visual Studio.  I am trying to edit the code in an HTML editor.  I know how to add references in VS.  I have all other references imported via: <%@ Import Namespace="abcdef" %>, but I can't do the same with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Comment: Importing namespace doesn't add a reference. It's just brings namespaces into scope.

Comment: mason.  Okay, thank you for the clarification on that.  The part of my question where I mentioned I am new to this, for some reason, was edited out.  This is the most confusing part of C# for me and I was just asking for help.  Thanks for some.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio to test this code example, you must first add a reference to the Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library component and specify the Outlook variable when you import the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace. The Imports or using statement must not occur directly before the functions in the code example but must be added before the public Class declaration. The following lines of code show how to do the import and assignment in Visual Basic and C#.

[Ref :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462097.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462097.aspx//)